# convert nested json array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json array as such (truncated here for brevity):

```
[
  {
    "name": null,
    "code": null,
    "results": [
      {
        "date": "2012-04-28T06:00:00.000Z",
        "name": null,
        "value": 135,
        "unit": "MG/DL",
        "code": null
      },
      {
        "date": "2012-04-28T06:00:00.000Z",
        "name": null,
        "value": 59,
        "unit": "MG/DL",
        "code": null
      }
    ]
  },
etc, etc,
]
```

I want to convert it to javascript array so I can extract the date and value to plot it.  I've seen stuff about eval and JSON.parse but can't figure out how to access the values properly.

The json text is called labs so I do:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(labs);
alert("obj.length="+obj.length);    //correctly shows 22 objects
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        alert("prop: " +prop + " value: " +obj[prop]);
    }
}
```

The output is 
prop: 0 value:[object Object]
prop: 1 value:[object Object]
etc.

How do I get the date field and the value field?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking to iterate over `results` within your array so you pull the individual date/value fields (like `results[0]['date']`, `results[1]['date']`, etc..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the 1st `"date"` with:

```
obj[0].results[0].date
```

Based on that, you can nest loops for each `0`. The 1st based on `obj`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

The other based on each of the nested `"results"` within `obj`:

```
    var results = obj[i].results;

    for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        // ...
    }
```

Within which you can alert the fields you're after:

```
        alert("Date: " + results[j].date + "\nValue: " + results[j].value);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  All makes sense now.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your loop in a regular old for loop. Right now you have an array of objects.

```
for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in obj[i]) {
        if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            alert("prop: " +prop + " value: " +obj[i][prop]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The outer loop correctly takes it through the 22 objects.  The inner loop correctly picks up the name and code values.  But when it gets to the Results object, it outputs a bunch of [object Object],[object Object], etc

Comment: I'm not going to do all of the work for you. I thought it was pretty obvious how to get any inner objects or arrays or values since I provided the methods needed to access any particular inner element.